# Couchbase - SELECT a subset of fields from array of objects

Tags: couchbase

I am using the `travel-sample` data set, and am running the following query:

```
SELECT id, schedule FROM `travel-sample`WHERE type = "route" LIMIT 1;
```

It is returning with the following results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10000,
    "schedule": [
      {
        "day": 0,
        "flight": "AF198",
        "utc": "10:13:00"
      },
      {
        "day": 0,
        "flight": "AF547",
        "utc": "19:14:00"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

However, I don't want to return the `schedule.$.day` field; i.e. I want my results to be:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10000,
    "schedule": [
      {
        "flight": "AF198",
        "utc": "10:13:00"
      },
      {
        "flight": "AF547",
        "utc": "19:14:00"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I `SELECT` only a subset of object fields from an array of objects?

---

I have tried `UNNEST` but I don't want to have a separate record for each `schedule` element - I want the `schedule` elements to remain nested inside the document.

I have also tried using `OBJECT_REMOVE`

```
SELECT id, ARRAY OBJECT_REMOVE(x, 'day') FOR x in schedule END AS schedule FROM `travel-sample` WHERE type = "route" LIMIT 1;
```

But I want to whitelist rather than blacklist fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last attempt was close. Instead of using `OBJECT_REMOVE`, you can simply construct the object you want returned.

```
SELECT id, ARRAY {"flight": x.flight, "utc": x.utc} FOR x in schedule END AS schedule FROM `travel-sample` WHERE type = "route" LIMIT 1;
```

You will get the following results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10000,
    "schedule": [
      {
        "flight": "AF198",
        "utc": "10:13:00"
      },
      {
        "flight": "AF547",
        "utc": "19:14:00"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```