# How to retrieve a subset of fields from array of objects using the Couchbase sub-document API?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am trying to write a lookup which returns an array from a document and skipping some fields:

```
 {
    "id": 10000,
    "schedule": [
      {
        "day": 0,
        "flight": "AF198",
        "utc": "10:13:00"
      },
      {
        "day": 0,
        "flight": "AF547",
        "utc": "19:14:00"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

I would like to get all schedule items but only the flight properties. I want to get something like this:

```
[
   { 
       "flight: "AF198"
   },
   { 
       "flight: "AF547"
   },
   ...
]
```

`bucket.lookupIn(key).get("schedule.flight")` doesn’t work. I tried `"schedule[].flight"`, `"schedule.$.flight"` It seems I always need to know the index.

I saw that this is possible with N1QL.

[Couchbase - SELECT a subset of fields from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908546/couchbase-select-a-subset-of-fields-from-array-of-objects)

Do you guys know how to do this with the Subdocument API? Sorry if it is a trivial question. I just cannot find an example on

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/subdocument-operations.html

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase Subdocument requires the full path, it does not support expansion. In this case it needs to know the index of the array. There are a few other options:

1. If every path is known, then you could chain all of the subdocument gets. A total of 16 paths can be got at once: 
   `bucket.lookupIn(key).get("schedule[0].flight").get(schedule[1].flight")`
2. Get the parent object and filter on the application side:
   `bucket.lookupIn(key).get("schedule")`
3. As mentioned in the question, use N1QL.